# How to sign a certificate for s/mime and generate pkcs12 store with existing CA?

Tags: openssl, certificate, certificate-authority, thunderbird, smime

I want to create a certificate store file in pkcs12 format to use in thunderbird for s/mime signing and encrypting. I already run a mail and web server that use certificates signed by a CA certificate that I have created. I want to sign the mail user's cert with that same CA.

I loosely followed [this guide](https://www.dalesandro.net/create-self-signed-smime-certificates/) but adjusted my steps to fit my setup.

The CA cert is in PEM format.

I create the p12 certificate store like so

```bash
touch ./tmp.pwd && chmod 600 ./tmp.pwd
vim ./tmp.pwd # enter password

mkdir reqs && mkdir certs && mkdir Pkeys

CLIENT_MAIL="mymail@domain.tld"
CN="My Name"
BASE_FILE_NAME="mail_cert"

# generate request and private key
# NOTE 1*
openssl req -new -passout: file:./tmp.pwd -keyout "Pkeys/${BASE_FILE_NAME}-key.pem" -out "reqs/${BASE_FILE_NAME}.pem" -subj "/O=${O}/CN=${CN}/emailAddress=${CLIENT_MAIL}" -extensions smime -config ./openssl.cnf

# check request
openssl req -noout -text -in "reqs/${BASE_FILE_NAME}.pem"

# issue the certificate
openssl ca -in "reqs/${BASE_FILE_NAME}.pem" -days 3650 -batch -out "certs/${BASE_FILE_NAME}-cert.pem" -extensions smime -config ./openssl.cnf

# verify
openssl verify -CAfile "CA.pem" "certs/${BASE_FILE_NAME}-cert.pem"
# NOTE 2*
openssl x509 -noout -text -in "certs/${BASE_FILE_NAME}-cert.pem"

# build certificate chain
openssl x509 -in CA.pem -inform PEM -out tmp-root.x509
openssl x509 -in "certs/${BASE_FILE_NAME}-cert.pem" -inform PEM -out tmp-cert.x509

cat "tmp-cert.x509" "tmp-root.x509" > "certs/${BASE_FILE_NAME}-cert-chain.pem"
rm tmp-cert.x509 tmp-root.x509

# make pkcs12 container
# openssl can't open the same file twice for password
cp tmp.pwd tmp2.pwd
openssl pkcs12 -passin file:./tmp.pwd -passout file:tmp2.pwd -export -in "certs/${BASE_FILE_NAME}-cert-chain.pem" -inkey "Pkeys/${BASE_FILE_NAME}-key.pem" -CAfile CA.pem -out "certs/${BASE_FILE_NAME}-cert.p12"

rm ./tmp2.pwd
# check
# NOTE 3*
openssl pkcs12 -passin file:.tmp.pwd -info -in "certs/${BASE_FILE_NAME}-cert.p12" -noout

rm ./tmp.pwd ./tmp2.pwd
```

The problem is that I can import the certificate in thunderbird just fine, and even select it for signing and encryption. But when I actually try to send a signed mail I get this error:

> Sending of the message failed.
> You specified that this message should be digitally signed, but the application either failed to find the signing certificate specified in your Mail & Newsgroup Account Settings, or the certificate has expired.

I have noticed that when I look at the certificate in thunderbird that it only shows the certificate itself, while I believe it should show the CA certificate in a separate tab at the top, as firefox does with the web certificates.

**Note 1**

The openssl.cnf file looks like this

```ini
[ ca ]
default_ca                              = CA_redacted

[ none ]
# Empty section

[ CA_redacted ]
dir                                     = .
certs                                   = $dir/certs
crl_dir                                 = $dir/crls
database                                = $dir/db/index.txt
new_certs_dir                           = $certs
certificate                             = $dir/CA.pem
serial                                  = $dir/db/serial
crl                                     = $dir/crls/crl.pem
private_key                             = $dir/CAkey/CA_key.pem
RANDFILE                                = $dir/CAkey/.rand
copy_extensions                         = copy
x509_extensions                         = cert_ext
default_days                            = 3650
default_crl_days                        = 365
default_md                              = sha512
policy                                  = policy

# policy for requests to be valid
[ policy ]
organizationName                        = match
organizationalUnitName                  = optional
commonName                              = supplied
emailAddress                            = optional

# These extensions are copied to the issued certs when signing it.
[ cert_ext ]
basicConstraints                        = critical,CA:FALSE
authorityKeyIdentifier                  = keyid,issuer:always
subjectKeyIdentifier                    = hash
issuerAltName                           = issuer:copy
authorityInfoAccess                     = caIssuers;URI:http://redacted/CA.der
crlDistributionPoints                   = URI:http://redacted/crl.pem

# Extensions for the CA itself.
[ CA_cert_ext ]
basicConstraints                        = critical, CA:TRUE
keyUsage                                = critical, keyCertSign, cRLSign, digitalSignature, dataEncipherment, keyEncipherment, digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage                        = serverAuth,clientAuth
subjectKeyIdentifier                    = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier                  = none

[ req ]
default_bits                            = 8192
distinguished_name                      = req_dn
x509_extensions                         = CA_cert_ext
req_extensions                          = v3_req

# this section is not used for mail.
[ v3_req ]
# [.. snip]

[ req_dn ]
0.organizationName                      = Organization Name (eg. company)
0.organizationName_default              = redacted
organizationalUnitName                  = Organization Unit Name
commonName                              = Common Name
commonName_default                      = CHANGEME
commonName_max                          = 64
emailAddress                            = Email Address
emailAddress_max                        = 64

# This section is used to add extensions when signing certificates used for email protection
[ smime ]
basicConstraints                        = critical, CA:FALSE
keyUsage                                = critical, nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage                        = emailProtection
subjectKeyIdentifier                    = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier                  = keyid:always, issuer
subjectAltName                          = email:copy
```

**Note 2**

The created mail certificate looks like this

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 37 (0x25)
        Signature Algorithm: sha512WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: O = [redacted], CN = CA Server
        Validity
            Not Before: May 13 00:14:38 2023 GMT
            Not After : May 10 00:14:38 2033 GMT
        Subject: O = [redacted], CN = My Name, emailAddress = my@mail.tld
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (8192 bit)
                Modulus:
                    [... snip]
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage:
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                E-mail Protection
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                A6:C7:14:89:03:6A:AD:95:9D:02:8C:D7:B3:0F:C6:5E:12:23:3C:FE
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                6F:73:01:97:F5:BE:29:68:47:56:24:35:91:8F:1C:6F:9D:80:8A:1D
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                email:my@mail.tld
    Signature Algorithm: sha512WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        [... snip]
```

**Note 3**

the output of the pcks12 info looks like this

```
MAC: sha256, Iteration 2048
MAC length: 32, salt length: 8
PKCS7 Encrypted data: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 2048, PRF hmacWithSHA256
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 2048, PRF hmacWithSHA256
```